# Web Starter Kit SASS not compiling

Tags: sass, gulp-sass

I am using SASS with web starter kit but it does not seem to be compiling my SASS. My CSS files are as structured as follows:

--------app

-----------assets

-----------------styles/

-----------------------app.css

-----------partials/

-----------scripts/

-----------scss/

---------------_bootstrap.scss

---------------_custom.scss

---------------_main.scss

---------------app.scss

REQUIRE SASS MODULED
    var sass = require("gulp-sass")

My Gulp.js file contains the following task:

```
 // Compile Sass For Style Guide Components (app/styles/components)
gulp.task('styles:scss', function() {
    var path = require('path');
    return gulp.src('app/scss/app.scss')
        .pipe($.sass({
            style: 'expanded',
            precision: 10,
            loadPath: ['app/scss']
        }))
        .on('error', console.error.bind(console))
        .pipe($.autoprefixer(AUTOPREFIXER_BROWSERS))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/assets/styles'))
        .pipe(reload({stream:true}))
        .pipe($.size({title: 'styles:scss'}));
});

// Output Final CSS Styles
gulp.task('styles', ['styles:scss', 'styles:css']);
```

WATCH SCRIPT (edited)
// Watch Files For Changes & Reload

```
gulp.task('serve', function() {
    browserSync({
        open: false,
        notify: true,
        server: {
            baseDir: ['.tmp', 'app']
        }
    });

    gulp.watch(['app/**/*.html'], reload);
    gulp.watch(['app/scss/**/*.scss'], ['styles:scss']);
//  gulp.watch(['{.tmp,app}/assets/styles/**/*.css'], ['styles:css']);
    gulp.watch(['app/scripts/**/*.js'], [/*'jshint',*/ 'scripts', reload]);
    gulp.watch(['app/assets/images/**/*'], reload);
});
```

Full Gulp file:

```
/**
 *
 *  Web Starter Kit
 *  Copyright 2014 Google Inc. All rights reserved.
 *
 *  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 *  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 *  You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 *  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 *  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 *  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 *  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 *  limitations under the License
 *
 */

'use strict';

// Include Gulp & Tools We'll Use
var gulp = require('gulp');
var $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')();
var del = require('del');
var runSequence = require('run-sequence');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');
var pagespeed = require('psi');
var reload = browserSync.reload;

var AUTOPREFIXER_BROWSERS = [
    'ie >= 10',
    'ie_mob >= 10',
    'ff >= 30',
    'chrome >= 34',
    'safari >= 7',
    'opera >= 23',
    'ios >= 7',
    'android >= 4.0',
    'bb >= 10'
];

// Lint JavaScript
gulp.task('jshint', function() {
    return gulp.src('app/scripts/**/*.js')
        .pipe(reload({stream: true, once: true}))
        .pipe($.jshint())
        .pipe($.jshint.reporter('jshint-stylish'))
        .pipe($.if(!browserSync.active, $.jshint.reporter('fail')));
});

// Optimize Images
gulp.task('images', function() {
    return gulp.src('app/assets/images/**/*')
        .pipe($.cache($.imagemin({
            progressive: true,
            interlaced: true
        })))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/assets/images'))
        .pipe($.size({title: 'images'}));
});

// Copy All Files At The Root Level (app)
gulp.task('copy', function() {
    return gulp.src(['app/*', '!app/*.html', '!app/scss', '!app/scripts'], {dot: true})
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
        .pipe($.size({title: 'copy'}));
});

// Copy Web Fonts To Dist
gulp.task('fonts', function() {
    return gulp.src(['app/assets/fonts/**'])
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/assets/fonts'))
        .pipe($.size({title: 'fonts'}));
});


// Automatically Prefix CSS
gulp.task('styles:css', function() {
    return gulp.src('app/styles/css/**/*.css')
        .pipe($.changed('app/styles'))
        .pipe($.autoprefixer(AUTOPREFIXER_BROWSERS))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/styles'))
        .pipe($.size({title: 'styles:css'}));
});

// Compile Sass For Style Guide Components (app/styles/components)
gulp.task('styles:scss', function() {
    var path = require('path');
    return gulp.src('app/scss/app.scss')
        .pipe($.sass({
            style: 'expanded',
            precision: 10,
            loadPath: ['app/scss']
        }))
        .on('error', console.error.bind(console))
        .pipe($.autoprefixer(AUTOPREFIXER_BROWSERS))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/assets/styles'))
        .pipe(reload({stream:true}))
        .pipe($.size({title: 'styles:scss'}));
});

//Watch sass

//---end Watch sass

// Output Final CSS Styles
gulp.task('styles', ['styles:scss', 'styles:css']);

// Scan Your HTML For Assets & Optimize Them
gulp.task('html', function() {
    return gulp.src('app/**/*.html')
        .pipe($.useref.assets({searchPath: '{.tmp,app}'}))
        // Concatenate And Minify JavaScript
        .pipe($.if('*.js', $.uglify({preserveComments: 'some'})))
        // Remove Any Unused CSS
        // commented for now as it doesn't work well with angular (ng-class for example)
        .pipe($.if('*.css', $.uncss({
            html: [
                'app/index.html'
            ],
            /* CSS Selectors for UnCSS to ignore
            ignore: [
                '.navdrawer-container.open',
                /.app-bar.open/
            ]*/
        })))
        // Concatenate And Minify Styles
        .pipe($.if('*.css', $.csso()))
        .pipe($.useref.restore())
        .pipe($.useref())
        // Update Production Style Guide Paths
        .pipe($.replace('components/components.css', 'components/main.min.css'))
        // Minify Any HTML
        .pipe($.if('*.html', $.minifyHtml({empty: true})))
        // Output Files
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
        .pipe($.size({title: 'html'}));
});

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    return gulp.src('app/scripts/**/*.js')
        .pipe($.if('*.js', $.uglify({preserveComments: 'some'})))
        .pipe($.sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe($.concat('app.js'))
        .pipe($.sourcemaps.write('./'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/assets/scripts'));
});

gulp.task('vendor', function() {
    var mainBowerFiles = require('main-bower-files');
    return gulp.src(mainBowerFiles(/* options */))
        .pipe($.if('*.js', $.uglify({preserveComments: 'some'})))
        .pipe($.sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe($.concat('vendor.js'))
        .pipe($.sourcemaps.write('./'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/assets/scripts'));
})

// Clean Output Directory
gulp.task('clean', del.bind(null, ['.tmp', 'dist']));

// Watch Files For Changes & Reload
gulp.task('serve', function() {
    browserSync({
        open: false,
        notify: true,
        server: {
            baseDir: ['.tmp', 'app']
        }
    });

    gulp.watch(['app/**/*.html'], reload);
    gulp.watch(['app/scss/**/*.scss'], ['styles:scss']);
//  gulp.watch(['{.tmp,app}/assets/styles/**/*.css'], ['styles:css']);
    gulp.watch(['app/scripts/**/*.js'], [/*'jshint',*/ 'scripts', reload]);
    gulp.watch(['app/assets/images/**/*'], reload);
});

// Build and serve the output from the dist build
gulp.task('serve:dist', ['default'], function() {
    browserSync({
        open: false,
        notify: true,
        server: {
            baseDir: 'dist'
        }
    });
});

// Build Production Files, the Default Task
gulp.task('default', ['clean'], function(cb) {
    runSequence('styles', 'vendor', 'scripts', ['jshint', 'html', 'images', 'fonts', 'copy'], cb);
});

// Run PageSpeed Insights
// Update `url` below to the public URL for your site
gulp.task('pagespeed', pagespeed.bind(null, {
    // By default, we use the PageSpeed Insights
    // free (no API key) tier. You can use a Google
    // Developer API key if you have one. See
    // http://goo.gl/RkN0vE for info key: 'YOUR_API_KEY'
    url: 'https://example.com',
    strategy: 'mobile'
}));

// Load custom tasks from the `tasks` directory
try {
    require('require-dir')('tasks');
} catch(err) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to watch the file for any edit in your `scss` files, and trigger the gulp task whenever such event happens.

Comment: Sorry, I am not an expert on this. Where do I watch the file? In the gulp file?

Comment: I edited my question above with the gulp.js watch script, it is is in the file so I do not understand why it would not be working. I also have the gulp sass module within the node_modules folder. Are my file paths correct?

Comment: Could you share a gist of your `gulpfile.js` ? That will be easier for me to see and debug.

Comment: Hey I think that my problem problem was that I had not included the styles function in the default task. See edited answer above. This now seems to be working, however I am getting errors with script task which is throwing a parse.js error and the html task which is throwing an undefined error.